# Current directory of a web app in netbeans

Tags: java, web-applications, netbeans

I am working on a web app i have java files in it which uses certain files.I want to specify these files using relative path in java so that it doesn't produce mobility issue.But Where should i place a file in a web app so that i can use relative path.? I have tried placing the files under `source package`, `web folder`, directly under the web-application.Please help.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to get the current directory of a java application is :

`System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsolutePath());`

Like that you can consider the given path as the root of your application.

Cheers,
Maxime.

Comment: It shows the path where server files are installed that is `C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.0.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\.`

Comment: And your files thant you need are not into your server ? (One of the folder under `C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.0.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\` ?)

Answer (score 0):

Read the file as a resource. Put it somewhere in the src. For instance

```
src/resources/myresource.txt
```

Then you can just do

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/myresource.txt");
```

Note: if you are using maven, then you are more accustomed to something like this

```
src/main/resources/myresource.txt
```

With maven, everything in the main/resources folder gets built to the root, so you would leave out the resources in your path

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/myresource.txt");
```